# Facing problem in solution of non-linear ordinary differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am a beginner in Mechanical Engineering research field. Recently I read a paper that contains one **non-linear ordinary differential equation**. The original author's have not explained anything about how the **non-linear ordinary differential equation** has been solved. 
I request you people to kindly help me by providing solution steps or any link that can help me to find solution of the same.
The equation is:

$\frac{dQ}{dT} + Q^2 - \frac{1}{({\beta}T+1)^2}=0$

and solution of the above equation as suggested by the original authors is:
$Q(t) = \frac{1}{2({\beta}T+1)} \left ( \beta + tanh\left ( \frac{1}{2}.\frac{ln({\beta}T+1)\sqrt{{\beta}^2 + 4}-2.arctanh(-2+{\beta})/\sqrt{{\beta}^2 + 4}.\beta}{\beta} \right ) \sqrt{{\beta}^2 + 4} \right ) $

Comment: It is a [Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation) and it can be reduced to a second order linear equation.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$\frac{dQ}{dT}+Q^{2}=\frac{1}{(\beta{T}+1)^{2}}$$
Let
$$Q(T)=\frac{A}{(\beta{T}+1)}$$
Then
$$\frac{dQ}{dT}+Q^{2}=\frac{A^{2}-\beta{A}}{(\beta{T}+1)^{2}}$$
Thus, for the solution, we want $A^{2}-\beta{A}-1=0$, this gives you two particular solutions $Q_{p, 1/2}$. Two more general solution containing a single arbitrary constant each can be obtained by then letting
$$Q_{1/2}=Q_{p, 1/2}+\frac{1}{y_{1/2}}$$
This will give two linear equations for $y_{1/2}$, and they are easy to solve.